# Find next sibling at the same level if exists

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, nextsibling

I'm curious whether is it possible to get next sibling only when is there some in the same level.

```
<font face="Arial, Helvetica" size="2"><b>Current:</b>
        90
        <b>Increment : </b> 5<br>
        <b>End Date/Time : </b>06/08/2015 21:00<br>
        <b>Last Made at : </b><font size="1"><br></font>
<font ....
```

So the point is that sometimes there is a text after `Last Made at : </b>` but sometime there is not.

I do this:

```
soup.find('b',text='Last Made at : ').next_sibling
```

The problem is that if there is not another sibling after `</b>` tag, it returns some data from another `<font>` tag which I don't want.

I know that it would be possible to use `font.contents` but in my case would be the better option something like

```
`tag.next_sibling_in_the_same_level_or_None`
```

I didn't find the option so I'm asking whether is there something which could help me in this case.

Comment: In the HTML snippet posted, *there is* another sibling after `</b>` tag. Notice that `<font size="1"><br></font>` is located at the same level as `<b>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the last  you do not want? if so see these.
infact, the last  is the sibling of the .you can prettify and print ,and you will see.

```
<font face="Arial, Helvetica" size="2">
 <b>
  Current:
 </b>
 90
 <b>
  Increment :
 </b>
 5
 <br>
  <b>
   End Date/Time :
  </b>
  06/08/2015 21:00
  <br>
   <b>
    Last Made at :
   </b>
   <font size="1">
    <br/>
   </font>
   **<font>
    not need
   </font>**
  </br>
 </br>
</font>
```

if you html is

```
<font face="Arial, Helvetica" size="2"><b>Current:</b>
        90
        <b>Increment : </b> 5<br>
        <b>End Date/Time : </b>06/08/2015 21:00<br>
        <b>Last Made at : </b><font size="1"><br></font>  
**</font>**
<font ....
```

then,i think you will not get the last .